# JScript error when downgrading to .net 2.0

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, jscript

I have a problem with a Web Application project which I have created. Originally I developed it in .net 3.5 and everything was okay. I have since been told that it needs to be in .net 2.0 (*sigh*) which has not only caused problems with the LINQ stuff I had written but has now also created a weird JScript error. The error occurs whenever I click a button within an UpdatePanel. The error is in one of the ScriptResource.axd files. The error is:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'PRM_ParserErrorDetails': object is null or undefined
```

and occurs at line

```
this._endPostBack(this._createPageRequestManagerParserError(String.format(Sys.WebForms.Res.PRM_ParserErrorDetails,parserErrorDetails)),sender);
```

The Pages are created using a MasterPage which is the Page that contains the UpdatePanel, along with an UpdateProgress control. Since changing to .net 2.0 this error has occured. When I changed it I added the System.Web.Extensions assembly to the web.config and also registered the controls from the same assembly. I have researched online and can't seem to find anybody with a solution or similar problem. Any suggestions or answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay as per usual I solved the problem almost instantly after posting. It seems the problem was that I was missing some sections from my web.config file. I had registered the controls using

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

and also the assemblies using

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</assemblies>
```

inside the system.web section but I was also missing:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
  <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
    <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
      <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
      <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

inside the configSections part in Configuration and also

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpModules>
```

in system.web.